# What are user fields publicly accessible through Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What are user fields publicly accessible through Facebook Graph Api (using an user access token or an app access token)? I mean not the logged in user.

So a call like this

```
GET /v2.7/{user-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

where `user-id` is not `me`

Comment: How about trying it?

Comment: @Martin. 
I have already made some tests. I'm searching for an actual and verified answer. Furthermore an answer written here could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Witout authorization, no data at all can be read from a user. You MUST authorize the user, and you can just use `/me` with the User Access Token.

If a user IS authorized, it depends on the permissions. Some data needs additional permissions, without additional ones you only get stuff like `id, name, first_name, last_name, age_range, picture, ...`

A list of available fields can be found in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: I mean using an user access token or an app access token. I will modify the original question, thanks.

Comment: it does not matter which token you are using, my answer is still valid. no data without authorization.

Comment: This is not true. In my test I can access cover, first name, last name and link. I know that also profile image is publicly accessible. I would know if there are others, maybe with some type of request to graph api that I don't know.

Comment: of course. if the user is authorized in your app only. you can´t access data of users who did not authorize your app, that´s what i am trying to say.

Comment: I'm talking about users who haven't authorized my app.

Comment: me too. no data without authorization, my answer is definitely correct. if you believe it isn´t, please provide an example.